# What to do if recombination of independent variables cause multicollinearity issue?

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, multicollinearity, bias-variance-tradeoff

Let's say you use a regression that has either: 1) interaction variables or 2) polynomials.  When using those features you may run into multicollinearity issues.  Do you know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you explain the basis for assuming such approaches are "likely to break ... assumptions"?  On the contrary, I would suppose that someone who is using such techniques is doing so because *not* incorporating them in the analysis would violate assumptions!  You seem, therefore, to be claiming that most users of these regression procedures just don't know what they are doing.  Regardless, this will be a problematic question to answer due to its reliance on such debatable assumptions.

Comment: When you construct independent variables that are simply recombinations of existing ones, the plain arithmetic suggests you would be more likely to break multicollinearity and exogeneity assumptions.  I am unclear why such position would be controversial.  Your comment suggests my question as phrased was somewhat insulting.  I beg to differ.  I did not claim at all that people don't know what they are doing.  I am simply seeking diagnostic testing interpretation ammunition to figure out how to get out related conundrum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such multicollinearity is matter of fact and does not matter substantively. With interactions, you can reduce such multicollinearity by centering the regressors constituting the interaction prior to entry into the model. With polynomial terms, the `poly()` function in R provides an approach that should not suffer multicollinearity, since it creates orthogonal polynomials.

But doing these things does not affect substantive conclusions nor does it alter the model quality. As far as I am aware, there is no reason to be concerned about multicollinearity that arises in this fashion. This also includes multicollinearity from dummy variable coding of categorical predictors. Paul Allison's blog post here is a [good entry point](https://statisticalhorizons.com/multicollinearity) to these issues.